# Project vector on a space defined by inequalities

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, vectors, projection

Let say I have a vector $d^T = [-1,3]$. I want to find the vector that is as close as possible to the vector d given the following linear inequalities:

$x \geq 0$

$-x+y \leq 2 $

I don't have a very large basis in linear algebra, but I believe this is called projecting a vector. However, while projecting it is often projected to a reduced space. In my case, I want to project it to a constrained space (I believe).

I found [this](https://www.quora.com/What-is-special-about-the-matrices-AA-T-and-A-TA-Why-do-they-show-up-in-things-like-least-squares-and-SVD-I-would-like-an-intuitive-or-geometric-interpretation-of-why-these-matrices-and-their-eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors-accomplish-what-they-do#) quora post that seems to describe the vector I am interested in. However, the post has linear equality constraints. When I introduced slack variables to my inequality constraints and applied the method in the post, the vector was not correct.

How can I calculate the vector which is as close to d while satisfying the inequalities?

Comment: You don't need much linear algebra here, you need to minimize $(-1 - x)^2 + (3 - y)^2$ subject to those constraints, because this expression is the squared distance from some vector $(x,y)$ and your vector $d$. Draw a picture of the problem. The minimium of this function is clearly at $(-1,3)$ which is at $d$ but this is outside of the feasible region. Since it's quadratic and always descreasing towards $d$, the minimum distance must lie on the boundary somewhere either along the line $x=0$ or the line $-x+y=2$. Do some substituting for x and y and you'll find the closest point to d is $(0,2)$

Comment: ^ for more general problems with complex constraints you may want to look at [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier) and [quadratic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming)